# DataFrame Split On Rows and apply on header one column using Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, loops, xlsxwriter

I'm working on some project and came up with the messy situation across where I've to split the data frame based on the first column of a data frame, So the situation is here the data frame I've with me is coming from SQL queries and I'm doing so much manipulation on that. So that is why not posting the code here.

**Target:** The data frame I've with me is like the below screenshot, and its available as [an xlsx file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dr_nk1MX4uh-Dqy2JQjcnTJxc0TgzrI1).

[image]

**Output:** I'm looking for output like the attached file here:

[image]

The thing is I'm not able to put any logic here that how do I get this done on dataframe itself as I'm newbie in Python.

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: @alex giving screen shot is I think is the minimize way. Is it?

Comment: Surely I'll do in future. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
df = df.set_index('Placement# Name')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%M-%d-%Y')

df_sub = df[['Delivered Impressions','Clicks','Conversion','Spend']].sum(level=0)\
  .assign(Date='Subtotal')

df_sub['CTR'] = df_sub['Clicks'] / df_sub['Delivered Impressions']
df_sub['eCPA'] = df_sub['Spend'] / df_sub['Conversion']

df_out = pd.concat([df, df_sub]).set_index('Date',append=True).sort_index(level=0)

startline = 0
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testxls.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
for n,g in df_out.groupby(level=0): 
    g.to_excel(writer, startrow=startline, index=True)
    startline += len(g)+2
writer.save()
```

Comment: Let me try@scottBoston

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston I'm close enough to get the answer.  looking at the code and wanted to check why you are changing the Date here to strftime because of this I'm not getting the dates correctly and getting output like "00-18-17", i want this to be "YYYY-MM-DD". Is there any way to get this format.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottBoston, its working fine now after reading DateTime module of python

Comment: How can i set the order of column here like ["Placement# Name" "Date" "Impressions" "Clicks" "CTR" "Conversion" "eCPA" "Spend"]. Currently its giving order ["Placement# Name" "Date"  "CTR"  and so on]. I applied reset index, which is not working.

Comment: After the pd.concat line add df = df[["Placement# Name" "Date" "Impressions" "Clicks" "CTR" "Conversion" "eCPA" "Spend"]]

Comment: @abhilashmishra If this answer has helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Sure I'll do, I've few queries to clarify. so for ordering while passing "Placement# Name and Date, I was getting index error, though when I passed the only Impression, clicks CTR and another column apart from Placement Name and Date, it's working. Also now how do I reach each of headers and the last row and how do I get the grand total which is the sum of each subtotal?

Answer (score 0):

Load the Excel file into a Pandas dataframe, then extract rows based on condition.

```
dframe = pandas.read_excel("sample.xlsx")

dframe = dframe.loc[dframe["Placement# Name"] == "Needed value"]
```

Where "needed value" would be the value of one of those rows.

Comment: what if the needed value gets vary every time. means in the current file they are three, but in future, they might be 4 or 5 or any count of numbers. So the logic i'm getting can apply on column [Placement# Name] and loop through each and when the value gets changed its gets inserted three rows and get apply formula and all. shift the columns to left and remove first header. but don't know how to write this on code.